# Преобразование объекта в массив и поиск

Tags: javascript

Создал объект, затем его преобразовал в массив, а после сделал поиск в массиве на числа. Но alert выводит пустое сообщение вместо нужных мне чисел. Где ошибка?

```js
let range = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
};

function convert() {

  let second =
    Object.entries(range)
    .filter(function(item) {
      return isFinite(item);
    })

  alert(second); // Должно вывести 1,2,3
}

convert();
```

Comment: `Object.entries` → `Object.values`

Comment: Помогло, но почему так? В чем их разница?

Comment: Так в доках написано же всё) https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries  и https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Comment: Там много научных терминов, я их не понимаю(( Если вам не тяжело, то не могли бы вы пожалуйста на простом языке объяснить нубу(((

Comment: Там нет научных терминов. У объектов есть ключи, а есть значения. Первый метод берет все наименования ключей, а второй берёт все значения. Вот и всё

Comment: Когда нужно использовать entries, а когда values?

Comment: Если вам важна работа со значениями (например фильтрация как вы указали в примере) - то `values`, если просто пробежать по всему объекту (ну, грубо говоря, посчитать количество свойств объекта) - `entries`

Comment: Там написано, что entries() возвращает массив собственных перечисляемых свойств указанного объекта в формате [key, value]. Я не могу понять, entries это преобразование объекта в массив или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно работать с объектом, то массив значений можно получить с помощью метода `Object.values(obj)`, где obj - "рабочий" объект

```js
const convert = (range) => {
  return Object
    .values(range)
    .filter((item) => isFinite(item))

}

const result = convert({
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3
});

console.log(result)
```

Но в вашей задаче нет смысла хранить значения в объекте, можно сразу использовать массив:

```js
const convert = (arr) => {
  return arr.filter((item) => isFinite(item))

}

const result = convert([1, 2, 3]);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Прочитал про values() в документации, там написано, что он возвращает массив собственных перечисляемых свойств указанного объекта в формате [key, value]. Я не могу понять, values это преобразование объекта в массив или нет?

Comment: @Человек да это преобразование объекта в массив. Сделать это можно тремя способами:
Object.values({one: 1,two: 2,three: 3}) => [1,2,3]
Object.keys({one: 1,two: 2,three: 3}) => ['one','two','three']
Object.entries({one: 1,two: 2,three: 3}) => [['one', 1],['two',2],['three',3]]

Comment: В чем разница между этими тремя способами?